# Showing that a sequence in a discrete topological space only converges if it is eventually constant

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

This is possibly a duplicate, but I'm trying to prove the following statement:

Let $X$ be a discrete topological space. Show that the only convergent sequences in $X$ are the ones that are eventually constant, that is, sequences $(x_i)$ such that
$x_i = x$ for all but finitely many $i$.

The definition of convergence given in the book is as follows:
A sequence $(x_i)$ converges to $x$ if for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_i \in U$ for all $i \geq n$.

My current line of reasoning is that if we have a sequence such that $x_i = x$ for only finitely many $i$ i.e. we have a finite index set I such that $x_i = x$ whenever $i \in I$, then we can define $U = X \setminus \{x_i : i \in I\}$  to be the set of all points excluding the points which are equal to $x$. Then, $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ since we have the discrete topology (every subset is an open set) and the sequence doesn't converge to $x$ due to the existence of $U$.

Is this proof acceptable? I feel like it's incomplete somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but it's not quite there: your $X\setminus\{x_i : i \in I\}$ doesn't contain $x$ and thus isn't a neighborhood of $x$.

Instead look at it the other way: $U=\{x\}$ is an open neighborhood of $x$. Now, argue that $U$ misses all but finitely-many members of the sequence.